# Refresh view in Acumatica

Tags: erp, acumatica

I have following situation: grid1 and grid2. After user press at button I generate records for grid2 with help PXDatabase.Insert. I need PXDatabase.Insert due to performance reason, so please don't say I have to use view. How can I refresh grid2 without refreshing whole screen. For example grid has button refresh. How to call it automatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can force application to refresh a grid by invoking `RequestRefresh()` on the view which is bound to your grid2. For example, in the discount calculation engine, you will find this code, to force system to refresh discount details grid:

```
discountDetails.View.RequestRefresh();
```